# Unable to get error message from completion handler of type Result

Tags: swift, alamofire, completionhandler

I am calling an api using Alamofire and trying to handle the error scenario. But I am not able to get the response for error in my completion handler implementation call.
Following is my Interactor code:

```
typealias CompletionHandlerType = (Result) -> Void
enum Result {
    case Success(Any?)
    case Failure(AppError)
}
func getLeads(stateId: String, completion: @escaping ([LeadInfo]?) -> Void) {
        let urlString = baseURL + leadsURL
        let params = ["user_id": UserDetails.getUserID() as AnyObject, "state_id": stateId as AnyObject]
        NetworkOperations.fetchPostResponse(url: urlString, param: params, completionHandler: { (result) in
            switch(result){
            case .Success(let res):
                guard let response = res as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                if let status = response["status"] as? Bool,
                   status,
                   let content = response["content"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    if let leads = content["leads"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        let array = leads.compactMap({ LeadInfo(json: $0) })
                        completion(array)
                    }
                }
                break;
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
                completion(nil)
                break
            }
        })
    }
```

API Handler code:

```
    class NetworkOperations {
    typealias CompletionHandlerType = (Result) -> Void
    
    class func fetchPostResponse(url:String, param:[String:AnyObject], completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandlerType){
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: getHeader()).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                completionHandler(Result.Success(response.result.value))
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(Result.Failure(.serverConnectionFailure))
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error in `fetchResponse` method of `NetworkOperations` class. But I am not getting it in my Interactor method.

Comment: Failure And Success start with small letters. It should be .success and .failure

Comment: My code was missing Result enum, I have added it now, please check it again.

Comment: There is a built-in `Result` type with generic associated values which is much better practice than  optional `Any`. And all unspecified JSON types are value types (`Any`), they are never `AnyObject`

Comment: Seems like both name conflicts your enum name and Swift.Result try to change your enum name

Comment: I have changed the name and also tried to use the Swift.Result but still my interaction is not able to call the method in network layer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func getLeads(stateId: String, completion: @escaping ([LeadInfo]?) -> Void) {
        let urlString = baseURL + leadsURL
        let params = ["user_id": UserDetails.getUserID() as AnyObject, "state_id": stateId as AnyObject]
        NetworkOperations.fetchPostResponse(url: urlString, param: params, completionHandler: { result in
            switch(result) {
            case .success(let res):
                guard let response = res as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                if let status = response["status"] as? Bool, status,
                   let content = response["content"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    if let leads = content["leads"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        let array = leads.compactMap({ LeadInfo(json: $0) })
                        completion(array)
                    }
                }
                break;
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
                break
            }
        })
    }
```

API Handler code:

```
  class NetworkOperations {
    class func fetchPostResponse(url:String, param:[String:AnyObject], completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[LeadInfo]?,AppError>) -> Void){
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: getHeader()).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                completionHandler(.success(response.result.value))
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(failure(.serverConnectionFailure))
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I replaced your Result enum with swift Result, now all you need to do is confirm to `AppError` to `Error protocol`

If it still doesn't work, let me know what is inside `response.result` in `Alamofire.request`